# Trouble fetching LinkedIn API certificates for certificate retrieval

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently working on integrating LinkedIn API into my application to fetch user profile information, including their certificates. However, I am encountering difficulties in retrieving the certificate data.

Steps Taken:

I have successfully set up the authentication process and obtained the necessary access token to make authenticated API calls.

I am using the "/me" endpoint to fetch the user's profile information, expecting to receive their certificate data among other details.

The API call to "/me" is returning the user's basic profile information such as name, headline, and industry, but the certificate information is not present in the response.

To narrow down the response and explicitly request the certificates, I tried using query projections. I used the "fields" parameter with values like "certifications" but still could not access the certificates.

Does anyone have a solution to get these certificates ?